# Git interaction with apple keychain

Tags: github, keychain

I have an open source swift project, that uses a third party api. I was looking for a way to store an api private key and found this apple [keychain service](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_in_the_keychain). I've done everything according to this link, saved the key to keychain on my Mac once and it loaded it perfectly in other loads just fine. I've ran into a problem when I committed the changes to GitHub. The keychain isn't updating on any other devices, where I clone the project. Is there a clean way to make the key secure but have it global for the project when loaded to git?

Answer (score 0):

The Keychain is not (intended to be) a shared key database across multiple Apple ID's, it is linked to your Apple ID, which in turn allows synchronisation between devices that are bound to the same ID, hence your *"it loaded it perfectly in other loads just fine"*.

Consumers of your project with different Apple ID's, or none at all, will not have access to your Keychain, or therefore your private key or API key. You'll have to think of some other solution for this, which, as far as I know, does not (yet) exist.